# Constrained regression with multiple sum=0 constraints

Tags: regression, constraints, finance, constraint-programming

sI'm running into a problem of how properly set up a model by using the Sum to zero constraint in Python. As a general overview: I need to estimate the so called "Barra Cross Sectional Model". I have 1-day returns of stocks, their exposures:

Style factors: set of continuous variable, not an issue
Country Factors: set of dummy variables
Industry Factors: set of dummy variables
Global Market Factor: value of 1 for all the stocks, let's say the intercept.
Given the usual identification problem in presence of multiple dummy variable, I'd like to tackle it by imposing the sum to zero constraint on the Country and Industry variables. I'm trying to do it in Python by leveraging on the Patsy - Sum function. Not considering the continuous variables, which don't create issues in this context, I'd have the following formula:

```
returns ~ C(industry, Sum) + C(country, Sum)
```

Assuming I have only 3 industries (energy, financial, industrial) and 3 countries (France, Italy, US), I would get the estimated coefficients for:

Intercept Energy Financial France Italy

If I understood it correctly, the constrasts matrix let you estimate the effect by comparing it to the last value of each variable, so to get the dropped/hidden value for each group, I need to compute it as -(sum of the estimated labels). For industries, industrial it'd be -sum(Energy + Financial), and the same for countries.

Do you think specifying the problem in this way, but most important my interpretation, is correct or I'm missing something?

here is a piece of code in Python to replicate the problem:

```
import random
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
from patsy.contrasts import Sum

cntr = ['france','us','italy']
ind = ['energy','financial','industrial']
n = 100

l = [[random.sample(cntr, k=1)[0],random.sample(ind, k=1)[0] , random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1)]  for i in range(n)]
input = pd.DataFrame(l, columns =['country','industry','ret'])

mod = ols(f"ret ~   C(industry, Sum) + C(country, Sum)  ", data=input)
res = mod.fit()
coeff = res.params
coeff.index = [x.replace("C(industry, Sum)[S.","").replace("C(country, Sum)[S.","").replace("]","") for x in coeff.index]
coeff[cntr[-1]] = -coeff.loc[cntr[:-1]].sum() #adding the dropped country
coeff[ind[-1]] = -coeff.loc[ind[:-1]].sum() #adding the dropped industry
coeff= coeff.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'factor',0:'value'})
print(coeff)
```

Thanks a lot in advance to all

I applied the Sum function from the patsy library to manage the issue.
What I would like to reach is to estimate the intercept representing the global mean of my returns (let's say, the global market), along with the effect by each country and industry.
The final result, in my mind, would be to estimate, for instance, the returns for a specific combination of country-industry by simply doing: intercept+country+industry.